# Modify x axis tick labels in R using gg plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, axis-labels

I am trying to modify the x axis tick labels in ggplot using scale_x_discrete but when executing it nothing is getting displayed on the x axis ticks.
I am using the code below

```
# a vector for weekdays
days_of_week<-c("sunday","monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday","saturday")

# calculating avderage ride time by the day of the week and user type
july_data%>%
  group_by(weekday,member_casual)%>%
  summarise(mean_ride_length = mean(as.numeric(ride_length)))%>%
  ggplot(aes(weekday, mean_ride_length, fill = member_casual))+
  geom_col(position = "dodge")+
  labs(title = "average ride time by weekday and rider type",
       x = "weekday",
       y = "average ride time (seconds)")+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = days_of_week)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

Comment: Hello Kartik, the reason may depend on what your data looks like. Can you put a sample of your data in the question that we can use to try and find a solution? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for some tips in posting usable data.

Comment: Hi! the data looks something like this weekdays<-c(6,7,1,5,2,3,4,7,1,2,5,4,6,7,3,4,7,6,5,2)
ride_length<-c(2000,1500,1425,528,1428,5127,4218,6158,9998,10125,528,2108,1486,50258,22858,2052,10825,2206,1978,1742)

Answer (score 0):

With the weekdays stored as numbers it's interpreting this as a continuous scale. You can transform this using `factor` in your `aes` call then the rest of your code should work as expected:

```r
library(tidyverse)

weekday <- c(6,7,1,5,2,3,4,7,1,2,5,4,6,7,3,4,7,6,5,2)
ride_length <- c(2000,1500,1425,528,1428,
                 5127,4218,6158,9998,10125,
                 528,2108,1486,50258,22858,
                 2052,10825,2206,1978,1742)

july_data <- tibble(weekday,
                    ride_length,
                    member_casual = sample(c("Member", "Casual"), 20,
                                           replace = TRUE))


# a vector for weekdays
days_of_week<-c("sunday","monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday","saturday")

# calculating avderage ride time by the day of the week and user type
july_data%>%
  group_by(weekday, member_casual)%>%
  summarise(mean_ride_length = mean(as.numeric(ride_length)))%>%
  ggplot(aes(factor(weekday), mean_ride_length, fill = member_casual))+
  geom_col(position = "dodge")+
  labs(title = "average ride time by weekday and rider type",
       x = "weekday",
       y = "average ride time (seconds)")+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = days_of_week)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]